# Publishing a self contained .net core 3.1 WPF app with a C++/CLI dependency fails-should this be supported?

Tags: .net-core, c++-cli

I'm trying to port a WPF app to .net core 3.1, and I'm running into issues with a C++/CLI dependency.  The main project is a C# .net core app, but it references a C++/CLI DLL as a managed wrapper to an unmanaged dependency.  The project works, and will publish if I make the deployment mode framework dependent (VS 2019 enterprise 16.5.4), but if I flip it to self-contained (which is part of the point of going to core), I get a very unhelpful publish error:

> Publish has encountered an error.
>   Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

The output log simply says:

> 4/21/2020 8:58:07 PM
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to > determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---
>
> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

Which is not helpful.  Looking through the output from VS in the publish step though, I see this statement:

> 3>Using "NETSdkError" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets..\tools\net472/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll".
>
> **3>C++/CLI projects targeting .NET Core cannot use SelfContained=true.**
>
> 3>Building with tools version "Current".

I tried digging around for an answer, but wasn't able to find one.  My question is-does .net core really not support publishing self contained projects when managed C++ is used?

Comment: I've just run into the same issue. Have you been able to figure this issue out? What version of `VS` are you using?

Comment: Nope, I'm just going to assume that the error message is valid, and that this just isn't supported.  Going to refactor the C++/CLI to C# with p/invoke in this case.  Would be great to get confirmation on why this doesn't work though.

Comment: So I did do some further reading (haven't tested it though) that if you use the `dotnet CLI` and specify an `RID` you should be able to publish. Below is a quote from MSDN: `When distributing an app with native dependencies, you may need to use the dotnet publish -r <RID> switch to specify the target platform you want to publish for`

Comment: Oh, you can publish just fine (and yes, you need to specify the platform), but you can only publish in framework-dependent mode, not self-contained (copy all the .net core dependencies to the publish directory).

Comment: This used to work at one point with .NET Core 3 Previews.